# Undefined function getAdminPanelUrlPrefix()'error in Laravel SaaS project after installing chatmessenger

Tags: php, laravel, chat, laravel-10, php-8

When I install the [chatmessenger package](https://github.com/syntaxlexx/laravel-5-messenger) in my Laravel SaaS project, I encounter an error:

> Call to undefined function getAdminPanelUrlPrefix()

Below is the error I get in my code editor.

[image]

[image]

And this is the error I get on the browser:
[image]

I'm unsure of the cause of this issue. However, when I remove the syntaxlexx/chatmessenger package, the project functions correctly.